# Chinese citizen Chinese passport transfer airline in Incheon, do I need B-2-1?

Tags: visas, transit-visas, south-korea, chinese-citizens, icn

Chinese citizen Chinese passport leaving chinese airport transfer airline in Incheon, do I need B-2-1?